# c# - Reading From CSV, Type Conversion Error

Tags: c#, csv, type-conversion, csvhelper

I'm using [CSVHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), though this seems to occur with the manual methods I know.

I'm trying to create some form of "save data" system using csv files, which will store all important variables that need to be loaded on the program running. Here's my code with generalized variable names:

```
        StringReader csv = new StringReader(SaveData);
        var load = new CsvReader(csv);
        string convertableString = "";
        load.Read();

        convertableString = load.GetField(0);
        day = Convert.ToInt32(convertableString);
        numberOfObjects = load.GetField<int>(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            load.Read();

            myObject[i].objName = load.GetField(0);
            myObject[i].objBool = load.GetField<bool>(1);
            myObject[i].objInt = load.GetField<int>(2);
        }
```

The lines that convert the strings to other variable types trigger the following error:

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

Specifically, the first line to throw this is:

```
day = Convert.ToInt32(convertableString);
```

This also applies to CSV Helper's conversion method however, this making the line (note that this requires deletion of the line above it):

```
day = load.GetField<int>(0);
```

For the sake of simplicity I'm showing both conversion methods and both return this (upon trying to convert anything, and yes "day" is an int)

My CSV file looks like *this*:

```
2,1,
Name, True, 45
```

I don't claim to have the best knowledge of coding but I'm getting there, though I can't really see what exactly is getting wrong, this isn't even my first time reading csv files and I've never experienced anything like this before.

Comment: Ok - you need to help us to help you. Which line throws the exception? Can you update your question to include an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Clarified it a bit better now.

Comment: @Dylannerd: What's the value of `convertableString` at the line `day = Convert.ToInt32(convertableString);`?

Comment: Just a hunch: Are there blank rows in the CSV? Right click>Open in Notepad and see if there are a bunch of rows with no data after your first data row. As @RB. noted, this is really a debugging exercise. What is the value that fails?

Comment: @Jacob H The csv was copied directly from notepad++. Also I'm away from my computer right now so I can't check the value at the moment, though it should be replicable if RB is able to right now. As stated in the question its any conversion that fails and throws an error.

Comment: Isn't field(0) the Name field? How do you expect it to convert to an int32? If I'm understanding CSVHelper correctly that is.

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation first as this seems like a pretty straightforward debugging issue the more I review your code: http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/reading#getting-fields Possibly implement `TryGetField` if at least to debug.

Comment: @Jacob H No, load.Read() makes csvReader go to the next record, with the first initialising it. I'm starting to notice a big mistake with how my csv file is laid out but regardless it doesn't explain why the day conversion fails.

Comment: You are passing the value "Name" here, yes? `convertableString = load.GetField(0)`. I mentioned nothing about load.Read() are you following the same conversation here man? Lol.

Comment: I know you didn't mention load.Read(), but it crops up twice here, the first to initialise the reader and the second to move on to the next record, regardless of the fact I formatted my csv file wrong (I think I did anyway), the first field will always point to 2, correct? Or am I missing something obvious here.

Comment: You tell me. What value do you see when you debug (f8) and hit the line where you set `convertableString`?

Comment: @JacobH I've found the solution a little while ago, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Side note... csv fields are not supposed to have spaces after the commas. This may parse fine for integers, but would definitely pollute strings unless you trim them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found the solution, firstly the csvReader was declared wrong, it should've been surrounded by this:

```
using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(saveData))
{
    var load = new CsvReader(fileReader);

    \\\Rest of code here\\\

}
```

What the original code was doing was sending the filepath to the CsvReader rather than the actual file, this meant that the first field was set to the filepath, with no other data present. The original code tried to convert the filepath into an integer, which caused it to crash. This resolves the problem entirely.

In this specific scenario (loading data on loading the program) it's also important to initialise your classes, so adding a line for that also prevents crashes.